# what is the best practice to create a query like php in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, treeview

i'm creating a tree view for my project, on my past codes i using php mysql_query(and other php build-in functions) to create a tree view and now i want to change it to codeigniter, here's my sample code of the two. i already autoload the database library in ci

---

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from mytbl") or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            /*another query here*/
        }
$sql = $this->db->query("select * from mytbl")->result()
           foreach($sql as $data){
             /*another query here*/
    }
```

---

not or to change?

thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please rephrase this question: "can i still use my php coding style in php or i will change it?"

Comment: I'd suggest not calling another SQL queries from inside of the loop.

Comment: I'd suggest not using mysql_* functions as they have been depricated. Use either mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter provides some great utilities for querying the database. For example your query could be written as:

```
$this->db->select("*")
         ->from("mytbl")->result();
```

However I like to get the **query** object first, so you can get useful information, like the number of results:

```
$query = $this->db->select("*")
         ->from("mytbl")->get();
/* Afterwards you can get the result by: */
$query->result();
```

In my opinion this improves the readability of queries quite a lot.

Of course you can continue using your old php style, but from a software engineering perspective, in order to mantain readable code, you should start using what the library provides you.

By the way, you can find more info in the official documentation:  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: thank you, i will use the active records of ci :D

Answer (score 0):

The mysql_ php functions are deprecated so you should stop using those.

CodeIgniter has an Active Records class which makes communicating with the database very simple. See the documentation: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: thank you, i will use the active_record of ci :D